# NGINX rewrite always returns 302

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am completely stumped by the behavior of nginx rewrite. I have the following 2 location blocks - the first one simply rewrites so that the second one gets called.

```
location /alt/digest/rewrite {
    rewrite /alt/digest/rewrite http://$server_name/digest/wms break;
}

location /digest/wms {
   ...
}
```

But I always get the following back on my curl app, when I hit http://server_name/alt/digest/rewrite

```
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is actually well described in the [rewrite documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite):

> If a replacement string starts with “http://” or “https://”, the processing stops and the redirect is returned to a client.

Remove the scheme and host part and rewrite to only the absolute path instead.
Also replace `break` with `last`:

> **last**
>      stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives and starts a search for a new location matching the changed URI;

```
rewrite /alt/digest/rewrite /digest/wms last;
```

Comment: thank you for replying. i have tried that several times but no luck. i still get the same 302. This is what i have in the logs:   2015/03/01 07:32:38 [debug] 21970#0: *378 http finalize request: 302, "/alt/digest/rewrite?" a:1, c:1
2015/03/01 07:32:38 [debug] 21970#0: *378 http special response: 302, "/alt/digest/rewrite?"

Comment: Ah, ok. thanks. but my underlying issue is this. i am proxy_pass 'ing to an apache for some authentication and i am using rewrite so apache  can see the same uri:

Comment: Ah, ok. thanks. but my underlying issue is this...since I couldn't state the details in the comment, I opened this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791427/nginx-to-apache-uri-mismatch

Comment: Does the rewrite actually change the uri from /alt/digest/rewrite to /digest/wms ? The reason I ask is that when I perform digest authentication on apache, apache still sees the uri as /alt/digest/rewrite and not /digest/wms. As a result, it issues an error message that </alt/digest/rewrite> does not match request-uri /digest/wms_v1/wms.wsgi>. Any help would be much appreciated.